# ¿Un Script cuenta como software, estrictamente hablando?

Tags: licencias

Todo tipo de código puede ser subido a repositorios en linea donde otros desarrolladores puedan acceder a el, esto hace necesario aplicar licencias para hacer explicito las libertades de dicho código.

Incluso un sólo Script puede ser subido a Github, y este puede tener un archivo de licencia. Estrictamente hablando las licencias se aplican a Software como tal, entonces puede un sólo script, de cualquier naturaleza, ser válido como software?

La wikipedia define software cómo cualquier pieza de código que de instrucciones a un computador. Contando como código y como computador hasta lo más primitivo o bajo nivel. Bajo esta definición es completamente valido. Qué opinión tiene sobre ello?

Comment: Creo que no has leído [ask]. Tus inquietudes son válidas pero no tienen que ver con el propósito del sitio. Y, como quienes colabormos aquí, lo hacemos por gusto y gratuitamente, nos tomamos el tiempo para ayudar a quienes intentan aprender a programar o a quienes tienen dificultades en su actividad de programar (nos ayudamos unos a otros), en general preferimos responder a preguntas que no den lugar "debates de opinión" que no llegan a ningún destino. En consecuencia, dudo que obtengas algo más que estos comentarios "desanimantes".

Comment: Te he votado positivo en una pregunta válida para que tengas reputación suficiente y entres al [chat] donde está duda y la anterior serán mejor recibidas

Comment: Software: *Es el conjunto de los programas de cómputo, procedimientos, reglas, documentación y datos asociados, que forman parte de las operaciones de un sistema de computación*. Sí, un *script* es software. Incluso, la documentación que acompañe a dicho *script* también es software (al menos en conjunto con el *script*). Saludos

Comment: Agradezco mucho sus comentarios, no quiero incumplir con las reglas del sitio, mis preguntas han sido debido a mi desconocimiento sobre como hacerlo bien. Leeré "Cómo preguntar" y evitaré cometer el error nuevamente. Gracias.

Comment: @Grem a mi no me parece que fuese una pregunta basada en opiniones, creo que se podía responder basándose en fuentes, tal y como he hecho en la respuesta, por lo que he votado para que se reabra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definición de script según Wikipedia:

> En informática, un script, secuencia de comandos​ o guión​ (traduciendo desde inglés) es un término informal que se usa para designar a un **programa** relativamente simple.

Es decir que un script es un programa informático. Viendo a su vez la definición de programas informático vemos que:

> Una colección de programas de computadora y datos relacionados se conoce como **software**. [...] De acuerdo a sus funciones, los programas informáticos se clasifican en **software de sistema** y **software de aplicación**.

Por lo que se puede que concluir que **un script es un tipo de software**. Dependiendo de la función que haga podría considerarse software de sistema o software de aplicación.

Más información:

- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa_inform%C3%A1tico